# Not able to get toolbar to collapse

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

Updated question. I tried to set the adapter from a string array in strings.xml and then set the adapter to the recyclerview (instead of the adapter loaded from cursor), but its still not working. I am posting the 2 files (activity_article_list.xml - the main layout file and ArticleListActivity.java) here again:

**activity_article_list.xml**:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/my_appbar_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="192dp"
        android:background="@color/primary"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:contentScrim="@color/primary"
            app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/technique_three_toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/days_list_3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**ArticleListActivity.java**:

```
public class ArticleListActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private Toolbar mToolbar;
private SwipeRefreshLayout mSwipeRefreshLayout;
private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;

Toolbar toolbar;
RecyclerView planets_list;
RecyclerView.LayoutManager layout_manager;
RecyclerViewAdapter adapter;
CollapsingToolbarLayout collapsing_container;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_article_list);

    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.technique_three_toolbar);
    planets_list = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.days_list_3);
    collapsing_container = (CollapsingToolbarLayout) findViewById(R.id.collapsing_container);

    layout_manager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    planets_list.setLayoutManager(layout_manager);

    adapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.days_names));
    planets_list.setAdapter(adapter);

    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    collapsing_container.setTitle(getString(R.string.app_name));

    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

}
}
```

**RecyclerViewAdapter.java**:

```
public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    String data[];

    public RecyclerViewAdapter(String data[]){
        this.data = data;
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.day_item, parent, false);

        ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder(v);

        return vh;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.text_view.setText(data[position]);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return data.length;
    }

    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        // each data item is just a string in this case
        public TextView text_view;
        public ViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);
            text_view = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.planet_name);
        }
    }
}
```

**strings.xml:**

```
<resources>

    <string name="app_name">XYZ Reader</string>
    <string name="welcome_xyz_reader">Welcome to XYZ Reader!</string>

    <!-- Days -->
    <string-array name="days_names">
        <item>Monday</item>
        <item>Tuesday</item>
        <item>Wednesday</item>
        <item>Thursday</item>
        <item>Friday</item>
        <item>Saturday</item>
        <item>Sunday</item>
    </string-array>

</resources>
```

Those that have finished Make Your App Material project, please give me some hints on how to add a fully functioning collapsing toolbar to the main activity.

Thanks.

Comment: Use this link : https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Handling-Scrolls-with-CoordinatorLayout

Answer (score 0):

Have you wrapped the whole view in CoordinatorLayout?. e.g.

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout >

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout >

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout >

            <ImageView />

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

I have removed the params.

This scrolling behavior is controlled only by the CoordinatorLayout. Any other container is not capable of doing that.

Comment: Yes, I have wrapped it within coordinatorlayout. Please see the updated question for more info.

Answer (score 0):

change your AppBarLayout code as per following...there are some lines missing in your code...this work perfectly for me.

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="112dp"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlwaysCollapsed|enterAlways">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/anim_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/index6"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">



        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

Comment: have you done it as per my code? because in your code you haven't added minHeight and layout_scrollFlags is also different in CollapsingToolbarLayout